# странно работают команды discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня есть команда позволяющая узнать кто создатель сервера и команда очистки сообщений. Если пользователь не имеет нужных прав для очистки сообщений выводится ошибка, **но** если после ошибки вновь прописать команду которая позволяет узнать создателя, выведется сначала ошибка связанная с командой очистки сообщений а потом уже создатель сервера.
отрывок кода с командами:

```
@bot.command()

#who_owner
async def owner(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f'☄☄☄', colour = discord.Color.blue(), description = f'**Owner of this server** `{ctx.guild.owner}`'), delete_after=4)

#clear
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)

async def clear(ctx, amount = 10):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f'', colour = discord.Color.blue(), description = f'You want delete `{count if count<10 else 10}` messages!')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 10)

@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(embed=PERM_ERROR)
```

Comment: У вас аргумент называется `amount`, а работать внутри функции вы пытаетесь с неизвестной переменной `count`. И в любом случае, что бы ни было указано в `amount`, вы все равно очищаете канал на 10 сообщений (`await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 10)`). В чем смысл этого аргумента вообще?

Comment: + Если вам нужно в `amount` получить от пользователя число, а не строку, выполните конвертацию типа — `amount: int=10`

Comment: @denisnumb По своей невнимательности и отсутствию опыта в discord py я не смог обратить на это внимание. Премного благодарен.